# How to put furniture against a painted wall without the paint sticking?

Tags: drywall, paint

I'm replacing the plumbing in my bathroom. I took the vanity away from the wall for access to the pipes. When I removed the cabinet, some paint and drywall came with it. The cabinet's back was made of masonite (or something similar) and had bonded to the latex wall paint.

No big problem; I was going to repair/repaint that area anyway. But now I need to put the vanity back :)

I plan on replacing the vanity completely with a pedestal sink in a year or two. I would rather not have to mess with the wall again.

Is there some way I can protect my new drywall and paint from similar damage this time? A plastic sheet? Wax paper? Something else?

Comment: just make sure the paint is good and dry before installing the vanity.  The paint that stuck was likely done after the vanity was in place.

Comment: The vanity top was removed? Or the entire cabinet and top?  What kind of top?

Comment: @Kris I took the entire cabinet and top. The cabinet has a wooden back, which is what stuck to the paint. Interestingly, the backsplash of the composite vanity top didn't stick at all...

Comment: @agentp Thank you! Sorry, but I wasn't clear. The wall was painted behind the entire vanity (top and cabinet). The vanity top came away fine. The vanity cabinet has a wooden back which was stuck to the paint. I don't know how long the paint was allowed to dry before the cabinet was installed...